# Sum the result of one column if one of the other columns is not distinct

Tags: sql

I want to SUM the total_students in case if the period code is not unique and leave it as it is if the period code is unique. For Example:

```
                         SELECT t.id as tutorId,g.sem_year,g.empno,g.period_code,

                                CASE WHEN NOT DISTINCT(g.period_code) 
                                     THEN sum(total_students) as student_no
                                ELSE total_students as student_no 

                         FROM tutor t  
                         LEFT JOIN tutor_students g ON(t.id=g.empno)
                         WHERE t.id=5
                         AND g.sem_year =6
                         group by period_code
```

I want student_no to have two different values based on the period_code. Here when period_code=555555 we sum total students to be 50 because it is not unique. In the other cases, we did not sum.Example:

```
period_code= 555555 and total_students= 30    THEN  student_no =50
period_code= 555555 and total_students= 20
period_code= 444444 and total_students= 2     THEN  student_no =2
period_code= 333333 and total_students= 4     THEN  student_no =4
period_code= 888888 and total_students= 15    THEN  student_no =15
```

Comment: The g.sem_year condition in the WHERE clause makes the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. Move it to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want window function with `count()`:

```
SELECT t.id as tutorId, g.sem_year, g.empno, g.period_code,
       COUNT(g.empno) OVER (PARTITION BY g.period_code) as student_no    
FROM tutor t INNER JOIN 
     tutor_students g 
     ON t.id = g.empno
WHERE t.id = 5 AND g.sem_year = 6;
```

**EDIT :** You can use other window function with sub-query :

```
SELECT t.*,
       (CASE WHEN total_students <> max_student_no THEN student_sum END) AS student_no_1
FROM(SELECT t.id as tutorId, g.sem_year, g.empno, g.period_code,
            SUM(total_students) OVER (PARTITION BY g.period_code) as student_sum,
            MAX(total_students) OVER (PARTITION BY g.period_code) as max_student_no    
     FROM tutor t INNER JOIN 
          tutor_students g 
          ON t.id = g.empno
     WHERE t.id = 5 AND g.sem_year = 6
    ) t;
```